# boost condition. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, boost, conditional-statements, boost-thread

```
boost::condition_variable cond;
boost::mutex mut;

void Database::run()
{
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mut);

    while(true)
    {
        while(queries_queue.empty())
            cond.wait(lock);

        mysqlpp::Query* q = queries_queue.front(); // <<< CRASHES HERE <<<
        q->execute();
        queries_queue.pop_front();
    }
}

void Database::Execute(mysqlpp::Query* q)
{
    {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mut);
        queries_queue.push_back(q);
    }
    cond.notify_one();
}
```

run is executed by boost::thread.
 Execute is called by main program thread to queue an operation.
 However, it crashes after waking from the conditional wait.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: btw, you should give your condition variables a more descriptive name

Comment: btw2, is it intentional, that the mutex is still locked while the function q->execute() is executed?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. The error might be somwhere else.

Comment: I do not know Boost.Threads that well but is it normal that you use `lock_guard` in one function and `unique_lock` in the other?

Comment: @wilx: The `lock_guard`/`unique_lock` choices are appropriate.

Comment: Just a question, if the line `while(queries_queue.empty) cond.wait(...)` is changed to `if(queries_queue.empty) ...`, will the logic be the same? Is the `while` loop a must?

Answer (score 2):

Your threading code looks good. The only thing that smells is mixing `lock_guard` and `unique_lock` but that is not a big deal. I am 99% sure, however, that your code crashes not where you stated, but on the next line - `q->execute();`. It seems that caller of the `Database::Execute ()` method is passing a pointer to a query object that is allocated on stack or, if it is allocated dynamically, it deletes it right after function completes. Later, however, your thread retries pointer to that deleted (freed or destructed) object and tries to execute it. Another possibility is that NULL pointer is passed to the `Database::Execute ()` which leads to the same result.

Comment: `lock_guard` is fine, if he doesn't have to pass the lock object to a condition variable.

Comment: Tried commenting q->execute and delete q out. The crash persisted. But when I removed both references to queries_queue, it worked.

Comment: @Vladimir: Is there something else accessing `queries_queue` possibly without locking? Plus, I don't see any `delete q;` in your example. It would help a lot if you could provide a minimal working code example that crashes. Otherwise it is always guessing. But the problem is definitely not in the threading code you have provided so far.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
while(true)
{
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mut);
    while(queries_queue.empty())
        cond.wait(lock);
```

Comment: Makes no sense to re-lock the `mutex`. That is what `condition::wait` for meant for.

Comment: @Vlad: I think aaa means moving the `boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mut);` from function scope to `while(true)` scope in `Database::run` not adding another one.

Comment: @Eugen: Exactly, and that will introduce lock/unlock on every interation of `while` loop. Which is very harmful.